# How to determine compiled iOS as Distribution > In House

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

As I know we could setup iOS distribution as ad hoc, but how to remotebuild to build as distribution as in house ipa?

[image]

I follow the http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#ios and didn't see any step to setup this workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova has started supporting packaging properties through "build.json" which you can add at the root of your project. The packaging document [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme), explains this for Android platform.

For iOS, you will have to refer to the same document to get the Code-Signing Identity (.CER) file and the Provisioning Profile (In house distribution). The you can add those into build.json as following properties:

```
{
  "ios" : {
      "release" : { 
         "codeSignIdentity" : "[complete path to downloaded .CER file]"
         "provisioningProfile" : "[complete path to the downloaded provisioning profile]"
       }   
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have problems with this.

SOak (PM - Microsoft)

Comment: @subhang oak, That was what I wanted. Thanks, if this could write into the document that would be helpful.

Comment: question about this settings. complete path means that full path on Mac or we just set the name of .cer file and provisioningProfile?