# VS2015 Cordova: Unable to deploy to iOS, error: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I'm getting the below error when trying to deploy from VS2015 to an iOS device:

```
Http 404: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile
```

This was working previously, with my `build.json` file looking similar to the below:

```
  "ios": {
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "C:\\ios_distribution.cer",
      "provisioningProfile":  "C:\\app_name.mobileprovision"
    }
  }
```

Any ideas? The profile is still active in XCode.

Note: the build succeeds:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My confusion was this: when building to iOS for testing/debug, you do a "Build and Run" (aka F5), but when you are ready to do the production build, you must just choose Build in Visual Studio, not Build and Run. That is because Apple does not allow folks to run the production package on your remote iOS device. So just build (your message indicates that the build was successful). Then, assuming you've got the certificate and provisioning profile configured properly, you then open up the project in XCode (on your remote Mac) to submit to iTunes Connect.

Comment: I have a question: how you can test your app before submitting it to Apple? Indeed I found on the mac the .ipa but can't install it on the phone, and I prefer to test the release file before submitting it to Apple....Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You do this by setting your visual studio build settings to Debug / IOS / Device and hitting F5, while having the iPhone attached to your remote Mac. MS has updated their documentation since this original issue was created. Check this page for help: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/

Comment: Thanks Douglas, unfortunately my Release configuration is quite different from the Debug's one. Indeed, server url, some files, some process are different (minification, uglification, ...) and ideally I wanted to deploy on device the "release" app to be sure that the exact file that I will send to apple is correct. If it's impossible, then I will just give a try and prey....

Answer (score 1):

The code signing and mobile provisioning profiles need to be installed on the OSX machine not referenced by file path.  You then specify an identity like "iPhone Developer: Your Name (DSAFASD)" and the UUID of the provisioning profile.

Though related to VSTS, this article can tell you how to get the full signing identity and UUID of the provisioning profile you want to use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/apps/secure-certs#iosinstall

Comment: According to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752454/how-to-determine-compiled-ios-as-distribution-in-house, you should be able to do this from within the build.json file.

Also note that this was working fine a few weeks ago so it is definitely possible. See this comment: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#comment-2398920195

Comment: I've never seen that work personally, but regardless, the paths you list are on your Windows machine so they won't work.  They'd need to be either relative to the project or on the OSX machine.

Comment: Yes but how to find the XCode project on the Mac machine? IN my setup, Visual Studio Cordova seems to be recreating the Xcode project each time I build from Visual Studio, in the .taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/XXX directory. If I update the build settings in XCode for this particular XCOde Project, it is no longer referenced in future builds from Visual Studio cordova

Comment: @Darshan, yes. My confusion was this: when building to iOS for testing/debug, you do a "Build and Run" (aka F5), but when you are ready to do the production build, you must just choose Build in Visual Studio, not Build and Run. That is because Apple does not allow folks to run the production package on your remote iOS device. So just build (your message indicates that the build was successful). Then, assuming you've got the certificate and provisioning profile configured properly, you then open up the project in XCode (on your remote Mac) to submit to iTunes Connect.

Comment: @DouglasTimms, thanks for this! If you post an answer with this, I'll accept it if you want.